# A coin is tossed six times. What is the probability of getting at least four heads on the tosses?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> A coin is tossed six times. What is the probability of getting at
>   least four heads on the tosses?

I have solved the problem like this:

probability of getting 2 tail =  ${}_6C_4  \times (\frac{1}{2}^6)$

probability of getting 1 tail = $_6C_5  \times (\frac{1}{2}^6)$

There for the probability of getting least four heads on the tosses is the  total probability minus  the probability of getting  the probability of getting 2 tail and probability of getting 1 tail.

Where am I wrong? Can you fix my probelm?

Comment: You should not write $(\frac12^6)$ if you mean $(\frac12)^6$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the probability that you get **no** tails--that is to say, the probability of getting at least four heads includes the event that you get **all** heads in $6$ tosses.

Also, implied in your question is the property that the coin is actually *fair*.  Without this assumption, you cannot obtain a numerical result.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add, that in that specific case, there is easier solution.

you could just calculate the probability of getting 3 tails and 3 heads

which is:

${}_6C_3  \times (\frac{1}{2})^6$.

if it not that case there are only 2 other cases:

1. at least 4 heads.
2. at least 4 tails.

because the probability of the above to cases is equal.than the answer is:

$(1 - {}_6C_3  \times (\frac{1}{2})^6) / 2$